# Cast typename to type in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to cast a string with a typename to a type without an explicit mapping (I need the type for an angular component factory).

With a mapping this is pretty straightforward:

```js
public readonly typeMap: Map<string, Type<{}>> = new Map<string, Type<{}>>([
  ['Type1', Type1],
  ['Type2', Type2]
]);
```

The problem is that I have many components that need to be mapped manually and it would be nice if I were able to omit the map.

Solutions I found, that are sadly not possible due to minification:

- using eval() (also this would be really dirty and unsafe)
- using window['Type1']

The rest of the solutions I found were mostly dead threads or provided the mapping as the best possibility. Do you have any Ideas how to solve this? Is this even possible?

Comment: Maybe something like this: `<[string, Type<{}>]>['Type1', Type1]`

Comment: @miselking where would that be an improvement? I'd still have to manually set the type...

Comment: @Andifined would you be willing to consider a decorator based approach ? The map would be kept by the decorator. You would need to explicitly add the decorator to each class so that would be the drawback

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir That would also not really help me since I need the map in only one class... I want to avoid it completely.

Comment: @Andifined If minification erases the class name then you have to capture the class - name relation in some other way

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thought so, but maybe a webpack pro or likewise can provide a better solution... There were at least requests for a feature on webpack, that will preserve the class name in a property.

Comment: You can use the window method with this trick.
window[Type1.name] = Type1
This saves you from minification mangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I came up with a nice solution myself thanks to the help of @Julian:
I replaced the mapping with a class decorator that is given the type-string and annotated every type I want to generate with it. In the decorator implementation I then added the type to the map, that is now dynamically filled.

This solution does not get around mapping each component manually, but I think it is far better than my previous solution since the mapping is now at the same place as the component and is not as easily forgotten about.

```js
// Empty mapping, filled at runtime
export const typeMap: Map<string, Type<{}>> = new Map<string, Type<{}>>();

// Classes that can be generated
@Type('Type1')
export class Type1 {}

@Type('Type2')
export class Type2 {}

// Decorator
export function Type(componentType: string) {
  return (target) => { typeMap.set(componentType, <Type<{}>>target); };
}
```

Comment: @David Already tested it with universal and AOT compilation, since that is what I use in my project... At least for me this seems to work. The map gets filled when the server starts, I think even before the Angular app gets bootstrapped.

Comment: Oh ok, good to know. I had tried using custom decorators a while ago and it did not work so well with AOT. Here is a related github issue for reference: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2901

Answer (score 1):

From what i can see it's not doable without lots of limitations. 
The name for a class is often never unique.

Mapping is a much more consistent solution and if you dont want to manually map everything then write a pre-build script to create the map. Using Typescript reflective API to annotate the classes is also a very good option.

Comment: Thanks, your tip to annotate the classes did really help me, although I didn't use reflections. I will post my solution below but if there is no better answer soon, the bounty is yours :)